# Cannot get the "until" paramter to work with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building an app in which I need to "backtrack" some datas. To do so, I read on the doc that there is a parameter called "until". However, it doesn't seem to work :

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?until=2011-01-01&access_token={at}

gives the same results than:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?access_token={at}

Did I do anything wrong or is it some kind of bug?

Thanks,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. Just tested this and it appears `until` does not work with a user's profile overview (`/me`), but does work for detailed information on the user (`/me/likes`). I could easily search for my likes years in the past using it. I would suggested drilling down and backtracking each specific element of the user you want to check. You could also file this as a bug/suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to get the likes count of a page at a specific date. Is there any other section I could find it? I tried to retrieve this data through a FQL query, but you cannot specify a date.

Comment: Insights tracks the change in likes for pages. I'm not sure if there's a way to grab those changes via the graph/FQL, but at the very minimum  you can go to the insights and export a history of the likes.

Comment: Thing is I would like to collect data from some page I'm not an admin. So I can not access to their insight system.

Answer (score 0):

When searching or querying connections, there are several useful parameters that enable you to filter and page through connection data:

limit, offset: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=3
until, since (a unix timestamp or any date accepted by strtotime): https://graph.facebook.com/search?until=yesterday&q=orange

Note that you cannot apply the "until" parameter directly to an object, it should be used with a connection.

For further information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/